# A question about a continuous function that satisfies the property $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists x<y\in\mathbb{R},f(x)<f(y)$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function that satisfies the property: forall $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $y \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x < y$ and $f(x)<f(y)$

I was able to prove (hard proof though) that if $a\in\mathbb{R}$ then forall $0<M$ there exists $M<y$ such that $f(a)<f(y)$ and take this for granted.

Prove that if $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=5$ then $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, f(x)<5$

But I got stuck. Thanks.

Comment: What is this: $\forall 0<M\in\mathbb{R},\exists M<y\in\mathbb{R}$? And this: $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists x<y\in\mathbb{R},f(x)<f(y)$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Now it is understandable? or do I need to write instead of $\forall 0<M\in\mathbb{R},\exists M<y\in\mathbb{R}$ just $\forall 0<M,\exists M<y$ (such that.. etc.)?

Comment: @JohnSaita I finally figured it out. I don't know about other people. I'd never write what you did, though.

Comment: If I will change $\forall 0<M\in\mathbb{R}$ to $\forall 0<M$ it will be more understandable?

Comment: My personal suggestion would be to choose between $\forall x\in \mathbb R\exists y\in \mathbb R(x<y\land f(x)<f(y))$ or $\text{For all }x\in \mathbb R\text{ there exists }y\in \mathbb R\text{ such that }x<y\text{ and }f(x)<f(y)$.

Comment: Now is it clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there is an $a$ such that $f(a) > 5$. Let $\epsilon = f(a) - 5 > 0$. If 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 5
$$
then you would have an $N$ such that if $x  \geq N$ then $\lvert f(x) - 5 \rvert < \epsilon / 2$.

Now $f$ being continuous on $[a, N]$ where $f(a) > f(N)$, $f$ attains a maximum at $x_0$ on $[a, N]$. This is also the maximum on $[a, \infty)$. But this contradicts the existence of a $y > x_0$ such that $f(x_0) < f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to prove the statement rigorously.